# Generalized rectangular tilings with no "fault lines"

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, tiling

I recently came across this question:
[One rectangle, indivisible](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36837/one-rectangle-indivisible/36844#36844)

The goal is, by tiling 2x1 rectangles, to create a larger rectangle that cannot be split into 2 smaller rectangles.

But my question is this:
if using **m x n** rectangles, when is it impossible to create such a tiling?

Obviously this is impossible for squares, but what else?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! What do you mean by "when is it impossible to create such a tiling"? For what values of m and n? For what size of the larger rectangle? Some combination? This question needs some more constraints on answers.

Comment: @bobble I think OP meant to ask "For which values of m and n does an mxn board permit an indivisible domino tiling?"

Comment: @Bubbler I interpret it to mean: If we use tiles of size mxn (instead of dominos) could it be impossible to make any fault-free rectangle with more than one tile?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis That makes more sense, given that "obviously this is impossible for squares".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Jaap's interpretation of the problem, I believe

> **all non-square tiles** can form a rectangle without fault lines.

First claim:

> All $1×n$ tiles can form a larger rectangle without fault lines.

Proof by example:

> We can extend [Roland's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/36839/71652) $5×6$ pattern for dominoes, so that some pieces are extended to $1×n$ tiles and some others to $(n-1)×n$ tiles:
>  [image] 
>  We can see that the marked $1×n$ tiles are enough to block all possible fault lines, and therefore it does not have any fault lines even if all $(n-1)×n$ tiles are divided into $1×n$ tiles.

Second claim:

> All $m×n$ tiles (where $m≠n$), i.e. all non-square tiles, can form a larger rectangle without fault lines.

Informal proof (might have a flaw):

> Without loss of generality, assume $m>n$. Put together some tiles side-by-side so that they form a $kn×n$ tile for the smallest possible integer $k$ (which is $\frac{\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)}{n}=\frac{m}{\gcd(m,n)}$). Since $m>n$, we know that $k>1$, so we can "shrink" the $kn×n$ tiles into $k×1$ tiles and form the rectangle shown above. Now, the shrunk $k×1$ piece has some seams at non-integer offsets, namely $\frac{mi}{n}, 0<i<\frac{kn}{m}=\frac{n}{\gcd(m,n)}$, so we need to prove that such seams do not form a fault line across the entire rectangle.

> Since $m>n$, we can observe that there is no seam passing through the squares at both ends of the $k×1$ tile. So the shaded cells in the above tiling are seam-free and therefore no fault line can pass through them: 
>  [image] [image] 
>  This blocks off all horizontal ($3k$ rows) and more than half of vertical lines ($k+3$ columns). (Remember that the diagrams represent $3k×(2k+1)$ rectangles.) Now it remains to show that the left section does not allow any vertical fault lines.

A lemma is needed at this point:

> If two $k×1$ tiles are placed horizontally with 1 horizontal offset, there is no vertical fault line passing the two tiles at non-integer offsets.

Proof:

> Assume that such fault line exists. It cannot go through the leftmost and rightmost square, so it must go through both tiles. Then the following equation should hold: $$\frac{mi}{n} + 1 = \frac{mj}{n} \\ mi + n = mj \\ m(j-i) = n$$ which is obviously impossible, because $m$ and $j-i$ are integers and $m>n$.

Back to the second claim:

> The lemma shows that the shaded cells in the following diagram block all vertical fault lines at non-integer offsets, which completes the proof that this tiling, when scaled up by the factor of $n$, gives the fault-line-free tiling of a large rectangle using $m×n$ tiles. 
>  [image]

---

As a demonstration of the construction, here are 2×5 tiles covering a 30×22 rectangle and 3×4 tiles covering a 36×27 rectangle, "seamlessly". You can see how 1×5 and 1×4 tiles are embedded in each tiling.

> [image] [image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partial answer.  It proves a fault-free rectangle can be assembled from rectangles of size mxn such that one dimension is not a multiple of the other.

The remaining cases can be converted to the 1xn case solved earlier by Bubbler.

> It is really simple.  Here is the solution for size 3x4.
>
>  A central rectangle is surrounded by four large squares made of n times m rectangles.
>  The gaps at the corners are just the right size for stripes of rectangles.
>  It works for any size mxn.
>
>  If m,n are such that one is not a multiple of the other
>  then the grey lines are guaranteed not to align across the black lines,
>  at least not across the black lines touching the central rectangle.
>  This makes the rectangle fault-free.
>
>  [image]