# Divide a board into two pieces without cutting a domino

Tags: logical-deduction, dominoes

Saw this question in the book, "A Moscow Math circle" by Dorichenko.

> Eighteen 2x1 dominoes cover a 6x6 board without overlapping each other or the sides of the board.
>
> Prove that, for any such arrangement, it is possible to cut the board into two pieces along a vertical or horizontal line without cutting a single domino.

First and more important question : Can you please  help me complete my answer to the above question ? This is my approach:

> Let us label the rows as a,b,c,d,e,f and columns as 1,2,3,4,5,6.
>
> Consider an arrangement where there is no domino occupying any 2 adjacent horizonal squares. For instance, let us say that there is no domino that occupies both 3 and 4. Then, in this arrangement, we can simply draw a vertical line between 3 and 4 without cutting any domino.
>
> Similarly, consider an arrangement where there is no domino which is occupying two adjacent vertical squares, say 'a' and 'b'. Then we can simply draw a horizontal line between 'a' and 'b' without cutting any domino.
>
> Therefore, the only way to not be able to cut the board without cutting a domino/ dominos is when there is at least one domino between every two adjacent horizontal boxes of the board i.e there is at least one domino each on 1-2, 2-3,  3-4, 4-5 and on 5-6.
> And also, there is at least one domino between every two adjacent vertical squares i.e there is at least one domino between a-b , b-c , c-d, d-e and e-f
>
> **Now, how do we prove that such an arrangement is not possible ?**

Question 2: How would you have solved the question ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [One rectangle, indivisible](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36837/one-rectangle-indivisible)

Comment: @StephenTG not quite. The proposed duplicate asks for “*the smallest area that **cannot** be split along a line into two smaller rectangles*”. The proposed duplicate isn’t a duplicate, but it *is* related.

Comment: Fair. The answers to the question I've linked only cover the cases up to 5x6, so this can be seen as more of an extension than a duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

Completion of proof:

Observe that because of parity there actually have to be two bridging dominoes for every pair of adjacent rows/columns. Now count them: 5x2 horizontal + 5x2 vertical: That's more than we have at our disposal.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why would parity dictate that there has to be two bridging dominoes for every pair of adjacent rows/columns?

Comment: As Jaap noted on a recent duplicate: If there was only one bridging domino crossing the border between such a pair, then that domino plus the rest of that border would split the rest of the board into areas of (6a+5) and (6b+5) squares (for some integers a and b), neither of which can be tiled by dominoes.